# Is invoking the distributive property necessary to prove that a + a = 2a?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was looking at an example from a text book of a simple proof using basic algebraic properties and wondered if one of the steps might not be redundant.

Specifically the step I've highlighted in the image, using the distributive property to get from a+a to 2a. Being in a textbook I'm assuming I'm misunderstanding something, but if so, I'd be interested in learning what.

Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: well the author just factored $1$ from each $a$ and then the result is $(1+1)a$, and since $1+1=2$ then $(1+1)a=\color{red}{2}a$

Comment: The book is merely being pedantic.  You do have to prove that $a + a = 2a$, and using the distributive property is one way to do that.

Comment: Ok tell me your logical steps as to why you think that $a+a=2a$ then. The way they have done it is standard

Comment: Depending on how pedantic you want to be... even just proving $1+1=2$ requires [quite a bit of work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica).

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thank you @Shaun for picking me up on the too generic question title and thank you to everyone else pointing out that, in a rigorous proof, you cannot just go from a + a = 2a.

Comment: It´s quite pedantic but for really basic stuff like this, in orther to justify it, we try to be more meticulus.